# Validation on CreateView and UpdateView in django always being triggered, even when model doesn't/shouldn't

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I am not sure why adding widgets in my GroupForm form in forms.py caused my validations to go haywire.  Before that they were respecting my models, now after adding widget attrs for everything it no longer respects the models and says a field is required for everything.  Is there some other item I missed when defining the widget?

forms.py:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    group_name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'1', 'placeholder':'Groups name'}))
    group_contact = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'2', 'placeholder':'Groups point of contact person'}))
    tin = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'3', 'placeholder':'Groups tin#'}))
    npi = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'4', 'placeholder':'Groups npi#'}))
    notes = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'tabindex':'5', 'placeholder':'Group notes'}))
    #notes = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'5', 'placeholder':'Groups notes'}))

    billing_address = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Address.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'tabindex':'6'}))
    mailing_address = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Address.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'tabindex':'7'}))
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '8',
                                    'placeholder' : 'Groups start date'
                                }))
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '9',
                                    'placeholder' : 'Groups term date'
                                }))
    change_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '10',
                                    'placeholder' : 'Groups changed date'
                                }))

    change_text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'11', 'placeholder':'Reason for date change'}))
    #term_comment = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'12', 'placeholder':'Note on group term'}))
    term_comment = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'tabindex':'12',  'placeholder':'Note on group term'}))
    group_phone = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$', 
                                error_message = ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
                                widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'13', 'placeholder': '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'}))

    group_fax = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$', 
                                error_message = ("Fax number must be entered in the format: '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
                                widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'15', 'placeholder': '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'}))

    group_term = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GroupTerm.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'tabindex':'16'}))

    class Meta:
        model=Group
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
```

views.py:

```
class GroupCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = 'ipaswdb/group/group_form.html'
    success_url = 'ipaswdb/group/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(GroupCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

class GroupUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = 'ipaswdb/group/group_form.html'
    success_url = 'ipaswdb/group/'
```

Group model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_contact= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    npi =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name = 'billing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    mailing_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name = 'mailing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    change_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    change_text = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    term_comment = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    group_phone=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_fax = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_term = models.ForeignKey(GroupTerm, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #quesiton is can a group be termed many times?
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    #provider_location = models.ManyToManyField('ProviderLocations', through='GroupLocations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because you added the widgets, it's because you actually redefined the fields and while redefining them, you did not respect your model's requirements. For example in your model

```
 mailing_address = models.ForeignKey(..., null=True, blank=True)
```

mailing address is allowed to be empty, but in your defined form field it's required.

```
mailing_address = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Address.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'tabindex':'7'}))
# You need required=False
```

If you want to redefine your own fields for the `modelForm` you can, then you need to respect your model while doing it. **However**, you can also accomplish what you're trying by using already existing dictionaries in `modelForm`. For example inside your `class Meta` you can override the widgets like this:

```
 class YourForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', ...)
        widgets = {
            # CHANGE THE WIDGETS HERE IF YOU WANT TO
            'field_1': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }  
        labels ={
            # CHANGE THE LABELS HERE IF YOU WANT TO
        }
```

More info at Django's `modelForm` docs: [Overriding defaults field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: Thanks this is working pretty well, though I am not sure how to add in here the field that was the RegEx type like this one:  group_phone = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$', 
                                error_message = ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
                                widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'13', 'placeholder': '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'}))

Comment: You can explicitly define those fields, just make sure your validation respects your model. They can be either `RegexField` as you have, or they can be `CharField` with validators. There is a validator example at the bottom of the [overriding defaults section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) but it's not necessary, you can override them however you wish.